# How to replace this nested loop?

Tags: list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nested-loops

The goal here is to get the text from a website and append it to the lists so I can then create a dataframe out of it. I managed to make this after lots of Google but now I understand its not the most effective way of doing it, been researching list comprehension but wasnt able to get a successful result.

```
containers = soup.find_all('td', class_=['TableRecords_EvenLine', 'TableRecords_OddLine'])

dateli = []
descli = []
amtli = []

for container in containers:
    date = container.select('div[id*=wtDataMov]')
    for element1 in date:
        seci1 = element1.get_text()
        dateli.append(seci1)
    description = container.select('div[id*=wtDescricao]')
    for element2 in description:
        seci2 = element2.get_text()
        descli.append(seci2)
    amount = container.select('div[id*=wtValorEur]')
    for element3 in amount:
        seci3 = element3.get_text()
        amtli.append(float(price_str(seci3)))
```

Ideas? Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it done using list comprehensions, it would look like this

```py
containers = soup.find_all('td', class_=['TableRecords_EvenLine', 'TableRecords_OddLine'])

dateli = []
descli = []
amtli = []

for container in containers:
    dateli += [e.get_text() for e in container.select('div[id*=wtDataMov]')]
    descli += [e.get_text() for e in container.select('div[id*=wtDescricao]')]
    amtli  += [float(price_str(e.get_text())) for e in container.select('div[id*=wtValorEur]')]
```